# Google Tag Manager - events not showing up in Google Analytics Real Time Events tab

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, web-analytics

I have added the below code to the head tag of my website, but when I navigate through the pages and make a transaction, the data doesn't flow through to the Real Time -> Events tab on the Google Analytics dashboard. However, I can see data when I go to the Real Time -> Content tab (it shows all the pages viewed in the last 30 minutes).

```
<script>
        (function(w, d, s, l, i) { w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({ 'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js' }); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&amp;l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f); })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-PCQXYZ2');
    </script><script type="text/javascript">
           window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
           window.dataLayer.push({
           "event": "transaction_completed_event",
           "transactionId": "12345",
           "transactionAffiliation": "18CA",
           "transactionTotal": 0.01,
           "transactionTax": 0,
           "transactionShipping": 0,
           "transactionProducts": [{
           "sku": "SKU-TEST",
           "name": "Product Name Test",
           "category": "Category Test",
           "price": 0.01,
           "quantity": 1
           }]
           });
      </script>
```

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are using is not relative to the enhanced ecommerce but standard ecommerce: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107169?hl=en

Have you configured a trigger on Tag Manager that is activated with a custom event named '*transaction_completed_event*' that fires an Analytics event tag?

Comment: Yes, I have now done this, thanks but I'm still not seeing any data in the Events tab relating to the transaction_completed_event.

Comment: In real time evnt tab you can see the category, action and label of the event you send to Analytics and not the details of the transaction. These details can be found in the Ecommerce report.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have enabled the option for enhanced ecommerce and 'Use data layer is selected' in your Google Analytics settings:
[image]

Comment: Thanks - under my E-commerce Setup tab, I can see the options to enable E-Commerce and to enable Enhanced E-commerce Reporting, which were both already enabled. However, I can't see the "Use data layer" option that you have in your screenshot?

Comment: It's settings for Google Analytics settings variable in GTM